# How to use asp:image in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, code-behind

I have a problem with rendering asp:image in code behind.
First I explain my method:
In `Default.aspx` I just use one label.
In code behind I make a string variable and fill it, then I fill the `lable.Text` by my string variable.
this is my `Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test_Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my form load function in Defaul.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = @"<asp:Image ID='Image1' runat='server'   ImageUrl='~/images/sc/tiraje.jpg' />
                    <br/>
                    <img src='../images/sc/tiraje.jpg' />
                    ";
}
```

Now this code must render two images. But first image used by asp:image doesn't work! I need to use asp:image in my string variable because my URL changes my result, for example if my URL is:

```
http://localhost:19551/website/test/Default.aspx
```

When I give it one "/":

```
http://localhost:19551/website/test/Default.aspx/
```

The second URL causes to change the src of second image in my string that I use in `<img>` tag. so that I want to use asp:image because it uses "~/" for src (imageUrl) that never changes by change URL!

Comment: use an asp:image control

Comment: Why are you using a Label? Why not using a placeholder control if you want to use serverside image controls? For placing html image tags you could use a literal which wouldn´t wrap your image tag in a span tag.

Comment: thanks for your help, you are true, but i need to add some html tags in the placeholder, how is it posible that add asp:image and simple html tags in a place holder, for example can u add 1 div after that 2 asp:image and then 1 <a> inside placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

The Literal control introduced by Abdullah ELEN is the easiest and it works. Like this:

```
       <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And then in the code behind, assuming  you have already captured the image source into a local variable (photo_src), you add this:

```
        Literal1.Text += "<img src=" + '"' + photo_src + '"' + "/>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using a label to render the images. Instead place two asp:image controls in the web form or use a placeholder control, such as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Application.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" />
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can dynamically create a new image control and set the image urls through codebehind by using their ImageUrl properties:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "../images/sc/tiraje.jpg";

            Image Image2 = new Image();
            Image2.ImageUrl = "../images/sc/tiraje.jpg";

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Image2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Orilux thanks for your answare, but i shoud do this with lable because i have many dynamic images from database and any other things so I need to do this in codebehinde by generate html and then fill it to my label for render in html page

Comment: The placeholder control that I have added is there instead of the label. Look at the way I create Image2 in the codebehind and add it to the placeholder.

Comment: I must generate code in code behind. I dont have any way palese help me in my question that how use asp:image instead <img> tag in code behind? or how define my url that / doesn't Influence on my <img> src proprties!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create in this way because `Asp:Image` is a server object. I have prepared for you a simple example below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="pageDefault" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <asp:Literal ID="literalControl" runat="server" />
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Write here your SQL query for image URLs..

    while(reader.Read())
        {
            literalControl.Text +=
                "<img src=\"../images/sc/" + reader[0].ToString() + ".jpg\" /><br/>";
        }
}
```