# How to get Image in ASP.Net with src attribute?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I've a problem, I've an HTML control `<img>` and I set in code behind the src attribute but nothing displays else the path is good.

I need to display image located (on my other web server) in http://example.com/my/path.jpg and display it on src attribute.

```
Protected Sub Btn_RechercheArticle_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
    Img_Article.Src = "http://mypath..."
End Sub
```

In my .ASPX

```
<img ID="Img_Article" runat="server"/>
```

When I inspect my HTML code in browser there is not attribute SRC.

Comment: have you tried `asp:image` control instead? [How to use asp:image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, i've tried to use with URL attribute and i've a src tag empty.

Comment: that is an html image element, I mean the asp.net control `asp:image`

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24228215/1593273

Comment: I think the problem is i use image in UpdatePanel. When i load the image in Page Load it work correctly but when i need to refresh the image in my updatePanel show nothing. (in my OnClick event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem, i've forget to add my Image in my Update panel. You can't refresh image with UpdatePanel where there is outside of Update Panel.